# How to prevent git push - only verified emails can be pushed

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

In GITHUB. How can I prevent unverified emails from pushing changes into the repository? sometimes code can be pushed even if user.email is not set. how to prevent this?

Comment: You will need a hook, not sure you can configure this on github. The author information and the authentication necessary for write access to github are two orthogonal pieces of information, completely unrelated.

Comment: I can do that via git hooks, I wanted github to refuse the push

Comment: I understand what you want, I'm just not sure you can get what you want.

Comment: thanks @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Be aware that I'm not *answering* your question, I'm just *commenting* with what I know, which may or may not mean anything. There could be hidden features of github that I don't know about, which is why I'm leaving these as comments, and not posting an answer. Here's to hoping.

Comment: GitHub Enterprise has a pre-receive hook that could do this. Otherwise, write a status check that prevents it from being merged to a protected branch.

Comment: So free version does not have it @osowskit